# select several fields from xmltable oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query with `xmltable`:

```
WITH sample_data AS(

    SELECT 10001 ID, '"A","B","C"' str, '"val_a","val_b","val_e"' numf FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 10002 ID, '"D","E","F"' str, '"val_c","val_a","val_z"' numf FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 10003 ID, '"C","E","G"' str, '"val_q","val_f","val_p"' numf FROM dual
    )

    SELECT id,
           trim(n.getstringval()) str
    FROM sample_data,
         xmltable(str) n
```

In result I get:

```
 --id--|--str---
 10001 |   A
 10001 |   B
 10001 |   C
 10002 |   D
 10002 |   E
 10002 |   F
 10003 |   C
 10003 |   E
 10003 |   G
```

Now I need to get this result:

```
 --id--|--str--|--numf--
 10001 |   A   |  val_a
 10001 |   B   |  val_b
 10001 |   C   |  val_e
 10002 |   D   |  val_c
 10002 |   E   |  val_a
 10002 |   F   |  val_z
 10003 |   C   |  val_q
 10003 |   E   |  val_f
 10003 |   G   |  val_p
```

How to update the query to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH sample_data AS(
    SELECT 10001 ID, '"A","B","C"' str, '2,3,4' numf FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 10002 ID, '"D","E","F"' str, '5,6,7' numf FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 10003 ID, '"C","E","G"' str, '8,9,10'numf FROM dual
), cte2 AS (
SELECT id,
       trim(n.getstringval()) str,
       NULL AS numf,
       rownum AS r
FROM sample_data, xmltable(str) n
UNION ALL
SELECT id,
       NULL,
       trim(n.getstringval()) numf,
       rownum
FROM sample_data, xmltable(numf) n
)
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, MIN(str) AS str, MIN(numf) AS numf
FROM cte2
GROUP BY r
ORDER BY ID, str;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=16689df1a6e1eb389c275b56247bc5fe)**

Output:

```
┌───────┬─────┬──────┐
│  ID   │ STR │ NUMF │
├───────┼─────┼──────┤
│ 10001 │ A   │    2 │
│ 10001 │ B   │    3 │
│ 10001 │ C   │    4 │
│ 10002 │ D   │    5 │
│ 10002 │ E   │    6 │
│ 10002 │ F   │    7 │
│ 10003 │ C   │    8 │
│ 10003 │ E   │    9 │
│ 10003 │ G   │   10 │
└───────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: ty for quick response but I meant something different. I need to add "numf" field to final result. Perhaps the numbers were not the most successful example.It's my fault. I will correct the question.

Comment: @IvanIvanov I won't update my answer third time. Please stop changing your question "in place" because you invalidate existing answer. **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f63a9e11757c7d700f3aed1611069db)**